# Exceed Redis maxmemory

Tags: redis

I am experimenting with redis 3.0 eviction policies on my local machine - I'd like to limit max memory so redis cannot consume more than 20 megabytes.

my configuration:

```
loglevel debug
maxmemory 20mb
maxmemory-policy noeviction
```

from here, I run `redis-server` with my configuration followed by

`redis-benchmark -q -n 100000 -c 50 -P 12`

to store a bunch of keys in memory. This puts memory usage for redis at 21MB on my mac, 1 megabyte over the specified limit. If I run it again, even more is consumed.

According to the [redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache) this should be controlled by my maxmemory directive and eviction policy, where an error is thrown on subsequent writes but I am not finding that this is the case.

Why is redis-server consuming more memory than allotted?

Comment: The OS' memory usage isn't the same thing as memory taken by user data - use `INFO` for that

Comment: using `redis-cli INFO|grep memory` and looking at metric `used_memory_human`, I am also exceeding the limit but unable to produce any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redis `maxmemory` policy control the user data memory usage (as [Itamer Haber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160475/itamar-haber) sas in comment). But here is some more complex situation with memory compsumation:

- Depends on operation system.
- Depends on CPU and used compiler (read as Redis x86/x64 used)
- Depends on used allocator ([jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/download/jemalloc/jemalloc-latest/doc/jemalloc.html) by default in Redis)

In real world application (as Redis is) you have limited rights with memory management. So your applicaion would compsume different memory for same application compiled as x64 or x86). In case of Redis data overhead is *nearest to 2 times* by memory.

### Why this important

Each time you write some data to Redis it's allocate or reallocate memory with allocator. The last (*jemalloc*) has complex strategy about that. In few words - allocate the memory size, lined up to the nearest power of two (you need 17 bytes - 32 would be allocated). Much of Redis structures use same policy. For example HASH (and ZSET becouse of HASH used under hood) use policy like that. Strings use much more brute strategy - double the size (with reallocation) while under REDIS_ENCODING_EMBSTR_SIZE_LIMIT (1 mb) or just allocate need size + REDIS_ENCODING_EMBSTR_SIZE_LIMIT).

So, is you limiting your `maxmemory` - the actual used memory in os can be a lot more and Redis can't do something with that.

p.s. Do not take for advertising please. Your question is very close to me. Here is [series of articles](http://habrahabr.ru/post/271487/) about real memory usage in Redis (they all in russian, sorry for that. I planning to translate them in english in this new years weekend. After that update links here. The part of translated [available here](http://redisplanet.com/)).

Comment: Would love to have the translated version and great answer

Comment: with noeviction set for the policy, shouldn't this still be throwing an error?

Comment: The noeviction is default value. noeviction  means that Redis would return errors when the memory limit was reached and the client is trying to execute commands that could result in more memory to be used (most write commands, but DEL and a few more exceptions).

Comment: @misterion Yep, seen it, commented and will feature in this year's **last edition** of Redis Watch. I also really like the blog's name and I've subscribed to it so I won't miss anything :)